# Who can give me the latest netlink programming samples?

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel

I'm writing a Linux driver using netlink to communicate between user space and kernel space. But I can't find some useful materials, because the netlink has changed from Linux kernel >=2.6.24. Who can give me some suggestions about how to create a netlink socket. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

The code below demonstrates the basics of sending data from a user space application to a kernel module using netlink. This code works on Linux 2.6.28.9 with the git version (ef8ba32) of [libnl](http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/). For more details, check out the libnl [documentation](http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/index.html) and the code for [iw](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/iw) which extensively uses netlink.

**Kernel**

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

#include <net/sock.h>
#include <net/netlink.h>

#define MY_MSG_TYPE (0x10 + 2)  // + 2 is arbitrary. same value for kern/usr

static struct sock *my_nl_sock;

DEFINE_MUTEX(my_mutex);

static int
my_rcv_msg(struct sk_buff *skb, struct nlmsghdr *nlh)
{
    int type;
    char *data;

    type = nlh->nlmsg_type;
    if (type != MY_MSG_TYPE) {
        printk("%s: expect %#x got %#x\n", __func__, MY_MSG_TYPE, type);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    data = NLMSG_DATA(nlh);
    printk("%s: %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", __func__,
            data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3],
            data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7]);
    return 0;
}

static void
my_nl_rcv_msg(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
    netlink_rcv_skb(skb, &my_rcv_msg);
    mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
}

static int
my_init(void)
{
    my_nl_sock = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, NETLINK_USERSOCK, 0,
            my_nl_rcv_msg, NULL, THIS_MODULE);
    if (!my_nl_sock) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "%s: receive handler registration failed\n", __func__);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void
my_exit(void)
{
    if (my_nl_sock) {
        netlink_kernel_release(my_nl_sock);
    }
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

**User Space**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netlink/netlink.h>

#define MY_MSG_TYPE (0x10 + 2)  // + 2 is arbitrary but is the same for kern/usr
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct nl_sock *nls;
    char msg[] = { 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef, 0x90, 0x0d, 0xbe, 0xef };
    int ret;

    nls = nl_socket_alloc();
    if (!nls) {
        printf("bad nl_socket_alloc\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ret = nl_connect(nls, NETLINK_USERSOCK);
    if (ret < 0) {
        nl_perror(ret, "nl_connect");
        nl_socket_free(nls);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ret = nl_send_simple(nls, MY_MSG_TYPE, 0, msg, sizeof(msg));
    if (ret < 0) {
        nl_perror(ret, "nl_send_simple");
        nl_close(nls);
        nl_socket_free(nls);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        printf("sent %d bytes\n", ret);
    }

    nl_close(nls);
    nl_socket_free(nls);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been away of kernel programming from some time now. So I can't give you a direct example on what changes have been introduced. I can tell you how I got to understand the netlink functions and how to use them, reading code. Especially code from NetworkManager or the wireless extensions (iwlib), since that was my area of focus 2 years ago. Those OSS projects always are on top on changes on the kernel and their code is not difficult to understand.