# What is the best way to use netlink from C++?

Tags: c++, linux, netlink

What is the best way to send and receive netlink messages from userspace in C++? I don't want to use C. I'm wanting to connect with the inet_diag module.

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to use C?  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299386/how-to-use-netlink-socket-to-communicate-with-a-kernel-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"There is no best, you pick the one most suitable for the task at hand." Possible ways:

- DIY construction of NL messages
- Aided construction with libmnl
- libnl3, but the API seems more complex than needed

Comment: Thanks, I went with libmnl, it is great, except for that I have to compile using C++0x, but that's not too much of a problem!