# kernel crash when trying to free the skb with `nlmsg_free(skb_out)`

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm developing a kernel module which send messages to user space via netlink.

To create a message (message to send): `skb_out = nlmsg_new(msg_size,0);`.

After sending the first message and before sending the second one, I tried to free the skb_out with `nlmsg_free(skb_out)` but this function cause a kernel crash.

- How to fix this crash ?

or

- Are there any other alternative to fre the skb_out after the send of the message?

here after the source code:

```
            skb_out = nlmsg_new(msg_size,0);
    if(!skb_out)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to allocate new skb\n");
        return;
    }

    nlh=nlmsg_put(skb_out,0,0,NLMSG_DONE,msg_size,0);
    NETLINK_CB(skb_out).dst_group = 0; /* not in mcast group */
    strncpy(nlmsg_data(nlh),msg,msg_size);
    res=nlmsg_unicast(nl_sk,skb_out,pid);
    if(res<0)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Error while sending bak to user\n");
    }

    nlmsg_free(skb_out);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not allowed to free the skb after you've sent it. `nlmsg_unicast()` will take care of that.

The reason is fairly simple: once you send the message it can be queued in the netlink socket for a while before anyone reads it. Just because `nlmsg_unicast()` returned it doesn't mean that the other side of the socket already got the message. If you free it before it's received you end up with a freed message in the queue, which causes the crash when the kernel tries to deliver it.

Simply allocate a new skb for every message.

Comment: I need your help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852866/netlink-giving-kernel-panic

Comment: @kristof-provost what if for any reason nlmsg_unicast() fails in sending the message? If you have a module that produces a burst of packets, sometimes nlmsg_unicast() fails with -EAGAIN. How to handle such cases?