# Sending a struct from kernel to userland via netlink

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module, netlink

I'm trying to send a struct from a LKM to userland, based on this answer: [Netlink Sockets in C using the 3.X linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215865/netlink-sockets-in-c-using-the-3-x-linux-kernel)

The code from the answer itself is perfectly compilable, but when I try to send a `struct` instead of a `char *`, I get segfaults in userland.

This is what I change:

**netlinkKernel.c**

I add:

```
typedef struct test{
    int a;
    char *b;
} s_test;
```

and replace

```
char *msg = "Hello from kernel";

---

msg_size = strlen(msg);

---

strncpy(nlmsg_data(nlh),msg,msg_size);
```

with

```
s_test x;
x.a = 42;
x.b = "The answer";

---

msg_size(sizeof(x));

---

memcpy(nlmsg_data(nlh), &x, msg_size);
```

**netlinkUser.c**

I add the same struct and replace

```
printf("Received message payload: %s\n", (char *)NLMSG_DATA(nlh));
```

with

```
s_test *x = (s_test *)NLMSG_DATA(nlh);
printf("Received message payload: %d - %s\n", x->a, x->b);
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your problem: your structure contains a pointer to other memory in kernel space (`char *b`). However, what you are sending to user space is only the pointer in the structure and not that other bit of memory (`"The answer"`). In addition, even if you were to also send the additional memory, `b` still is a pointer to **kernel** virtual addresses.

Your best bet is to make b a char array and copy the data into b.

Pointers inside data sent between processes or between a process and the kernel are generally very problematic. system calls that use structures of pointers, e. g. `man 2 recvmsg`, do not just send the pointers verbatim between user space and kernel, instead, the kernel does separate access to userspace to resolve each pointer.

Comment: This makes sense, but why the demo from the answer I link to works? The demo sends a ```char *```, not a ```char [N]```.

Comment: Also, this was just a POC, my real struct has a 5 char* and a pid_t, and maybe I'll add more. I think I need a de/serialization library. Do you know any (that will work in the kernel side, aka, no malloc/free but kmalloc/kfree and so on...)?