# Communicate between a linux device and Perl scripts

Tags: linux, perl, network-programming, ipc, linux-device-driver

I have a written Linux device (implement as a interface) and a perl script, I need those two to communicate among them while executing(perl to device). I have thought of writing to a file and reading from it. but i think it is not an ideal one. can any one point me to more good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the methods Joachim mentioned also look into creating a character or block device so you can access it through /dev/somenode. That's probably the preferred way if your driver is really offering a service or an interface to a device.

Alternatively, and better than an ioctl() interface, you can use netlink sockets. They're actually even easier to implement than ioctl()s, and are more likely to be accepted upstream.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of doing this: Either have one or more files in e.g. `/proc` that is written to or read from.

The second is to use special [`ioctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl) commands on the device file.