# Is there a way, to receive data in a kernel module without using a callback function?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, ipc

I am currently writing a Linux kernel module, where I have to send requests to a user-space application out of a callback function.

So what I need in my module is something like this:

```
int callback_function () {
   ...
   send_request_to_app();
   receive_answer();
   ...
}
```

I tried using generic netlink combined with wait_queues somewhat like this:

```
int response = 0;
DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(wait_queue);

static int nl_recv_msg(struct sk_buff *skb, struct genl_info* info) {
   ...
   response = 1;
   wake_up_interruptible(&wait_queue);
   ...
}

int callback_function () {
   ...
   send_request_to_app();
   wait_event_interruptible(wait_queue, response);
   ...
}
```

Similar to this question: [How to send and receive messages from function other than registered callback function in Netlink socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653257/how-to-send-and-receive-messages-from-function-other-than-registered-callback-fu)

This does not work for me, which I believe might be because of race conditions, since the `callback_function` is called frequently.

**Is there another way to receive an answer without using another callback function or is there a different IPC method that solves this problem?**

**Edit:** I am not trying to fix the code above. I am just looking for other methods/ideas.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "This does not work for me" is not a description of the problem, with which we could help you. "which I believe might be because of race conditions, since the `callback_function` is called frequently" - It could be many other reasons why your code doesn't work. If you suspect the messages to be arrived too often, then modify user-space application to send them less often and verify that kernel code works in that case. "Is there another way to receive an answer without using another callback function" - No, receiving a message is purely asynchronous event.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yeah, I have tried many different things regarding that problem, but since I did not make any progress, I was just looking for a completely different method. Not a fix for the wait_queue stuff. I will try to make my question more precise the next time. Thank you!

Comment: You may [edit] the question. Please, do that and update description of your problem so it can be answered. "I was just looking for a completely different method." - There are plenty other methods for interact kernel a user. Enumerating all of them would be **too broad** for stack overflow.