# Socket of which type for data sharing between Kernel and userspace

Tags: linux-kernel

Im new to socket programing . I wanted to send few data from Kernel to userspace. I wanted know socket of which family and protocol is suitable to create? 
UDP,
TCP,
RAW,
NETLINK,

It will be better if anyone explains usecase of socket types.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following socket API
`int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);`

1)Netlink sockets are used for communicating between Userspace and the kernel space. Check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299386/how-to-use-netlink-socket-to-communicate-with-a-kernel-module) for example.

2)TCP(of type SOCK_STREAM) and UDP(SOCK_DGRAM) are used mostly for communicating over network. These sockets are of the domain AF_INET. TCP is used for file downloading like application, where delivey and order is guaranteed. UDP is used in cases where latency is important, than delivery or retransmission. Like in the case of Live Video stream. Even a frame of video is skipped, it still should not go for retransmission and slow down the 'LIVE' effect.

3)Then there is usage of sockets for IPC(Inter process Communication). In that case the domain is AF_UNIX and the type used can be SOCK_SEQPACKET(similar to TCP)