# in linux kernel module programming can i use any library?

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel

is it possible that i use FILE I/O instead character device driver?

in my kernel module code i used character device driver source code

(ex. alloc_chrdev_region()....) it because i want to read any number from specific files and process them in module. but when i tried first time, i used FILE I/O in module code and it didn't work. okay.. simply..

character device driver is only method for interacting with user application in kernel module programming?(it include with block, network)

Comment: No; in the kernel you have to be careful to use libraries designed for use in the kernel.  You absolutely cannot use just any old library.

Comment: It's a terrible idea trying using standard library from kernel space. There are other ways of communication from userspace to kernelspace like. using `procfs` or `sysfs` entries.

Comment: okay i see. if i want to read some value in a file directly without using device node, how can i do in the kernel module?

Comment: Use [netlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html). Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299386/how-to-use-netlink-socket-to-communicate-with-a-kernel-module)