# string.h: No such file or directory upon trying to build using kbuild Makefile

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm trying to send a string to the kernel module from the user space and the kernel returns back  the string reversed. I followed a simple example [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299386/how-to-use-netlink-socket-to-communicate-with-a-kernel-module) and added strrev() function in the kernel code which is defined in the string.h header. But that gives me an error "fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory" and no other error. The user code is same as the sample code from the link. Can anybody explain why this is happening ?

### User Code

```
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NETLINK_USER 31

#define MAX_PAYLOAD 1024 /* maximum payload size*/
struct sockaddr_nl src_addr, dest_addr;
struct nlmsghdr *nlh = NULL;
struct iovec iov;
int sock_fd;
struct msghdr msg;

int main()
{   
    char str[20];

    sock_fd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_USER);
    if (sock_fd < 0)
        return -1;

    memset(&src_addr, 0, sizeof(src_addr));
    src_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    src_addr.nl_pid = getpid(); /* self pid */

    bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr, sizeof(src_addr));

    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
    dest_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    dest_addr.nl_pid = 0; /* For Linux Kernel */
    dest_addr.nl_groups = 0; /* unicast */

    nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)malloc(NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));
    memset(nlh, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));
    nlh->nlmsg_len = NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD);
    nlh->nlmsg_pid = getpid();
    nlh->nlmsg_flags = 0;
    
    printf("Enter a string for reversal:- ");
    scanf("%s",str);
    
    strcpy(NLMSG_DATA(nlh),str);

    iov.iov_base = (void *)nlh;
    iov.iov_len = nlh->nlmsg_len;
    msg.msg_name = (void *)&dest_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(dest_addr);
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

    printf("\nSending message to kernel\n");
    sendmsg(sock_fd, &msg, 0);
    printf("Waiting for message from kernel\n");

    /* Read message from kernel */
    recvmsg(sock_fd, &msg, 0);
    printf("Received message payload: %s\n", NLMSG_DATA(nlh));
    close(sock_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

### Kernel Code

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <net/sock.h> 
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h> 
#include<string.h>
#define NETLINK_USER 31

struct sock *nl_sk = NULL;

static void hello_nl_recv_msg(struct sk_buff *skb)
{

    struct nlmsghdr *nlh;
    int pid;
    struct sk_buff *skb_out;
    int msg_size;
    char msg[20];
    int res;


    printk(KERN_INFO "Entering: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);

    
    
    nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)skb->data;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Netlink received msg payload:%s\n", (char *)nlmsg_data(nlh));
    pid = nlh->nlmsg_pid; /*pid of sending process */
    strcpy(msg,strrev((char *)nlmsg_data(nlh)));
    msg_size = strlen(msg);
        
    skb_out = nlmsg_new(msg_size, 0);
    if (!skb_out) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to allocate new skb\n");
        return;
    }

    nlh = nlmsg_put(skb_out, 0, 0, NLMSG_DONE, msg_size, 0);
    NETLINK_CB(skb_out).dst_group = 0; /* not in mcast group */
    strncpy(nlmsg_data(nlh), msg, msg_size);

    res = nlmsg_unicast(nl_sk, skb_out, pid);
    if (res < 0)
        printk(KERN_INFO "Error while sending bak to user\n");
}

static int __init hello_init(void)
{

    printk("Entering: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    //nl_sk = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, NETLINK_USER, 0, hello_nl_recv_msg, NULL, THIS_MODULE);
    struct netlink_kernel_cfg cfg = {
        .input = hello_nl_recv_msg,
    };

    nl_sk = netlink_kernel_create(&init_net, NETLINK_USER, &cfg);
    if (!nl_sk) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error creating socket.\n");
        return -10;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{

    printk(KERN_INFO "exiting hello module\n");
    netlink_kernel_release(nl_sk);
}

module_init(hello_init); 
module_exit(hello_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

### Terminal window

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-1096-oem/build/ M=/home/Username/Documents/Task_KtoUcom modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1096-oem'
  CC [M]  /home/Username/Documents/Task_KtoUcom/kernl.o
/home/Username/Documents/Task_KtoUcom/kernl.c:5:9: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
 #include<string.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:337: recipe for target '/home/Username/Documents/Task_KtoUcom/kernl.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/Username/Documents/Task_KtoUcom/kernl.o] Error 1
Makefile:1585: recipe for target '_module_/home/Username/Documents/Task_KtoUcom' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/Username/Documents/Task_KtoUcom] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1096-oem'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Post the actual compiler command line.

Comment: Best to post your code here.

Comment: Do no include std library in kernel sources. It is just a different environment, things may break. For strings: standard library known that it can access also bytes after the string (e.g. to parallelize string operation, with full 32-bit or 64-bit operators), because it manage also the memory. So it uses it to speed up operations. Kernel has not such privilege.

Comment: Is the message payload `nlmsg_data(nlh)` actually a null-terminated string? It seems doubtful to me. Also, the kernel does not have the `strrev()` function.

Comment: @IanAbbott You are right. It does not have strrev()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux kernel provides string functions in the `linux/string.h` header:

```
#include <linux/string.h>
```

Different header name has been chosen on purpose: a set of functions, provided by the Linux kernel `<linux/string.h>`, **differs** from the set of functions, provided by standard `<string.h>`.

The header `<linux/string.h>` provides most of standard string functions, and has replacement for some other ones.

E.g. functions `strlen`, `strcpy` and `strncpy` are provided by that header and have the same semantic, as in C standard.