# How to use netlink for IPC?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipc, netlink

My project needs to do IPC by using Netlink and the reference is [Netlink unicast](https://github.com/argonlaser/talk-with-linux/tree/master/IPC/netlink/unicast). I had done some changes in code. Firstly, I started both receiver and sender, then I inputted the sender's pid to receiver and later inputted receiver's pid to sender. But the receiver didn't receive the message. I also refer [Is anyone using netlink for IPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238160/is-anyone-using-netlink-for-ipc), none of them were working. Is that any problem in my code?

Receiver's code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NLINK_MSG_LEN 1024
#define NETLINK_USER 31

int main() {
  int fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_GENERIC);
  //int fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_USERSOCK);
  //int fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_USER);
  printf("Inside recv main\n");

  if (fd < 0) {
    printf("Socket creation failed. try again\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Declare for src NL sockaddr, dest NL sockaddr, nlmsghdr, iov, msghr */
  struct sockaddr_nl src_addr, dest_addr;
  memset(&src_addr, 0, sizeof(src_addr));
  memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));

  //allocate buffer for netlink message which is message header + message payload
  struct nlmsghdr *nlh =(struct nlmsghdr *) malloc(NLMSG_SPACE(NLINK_MSG_LEN));
  memset(nlh, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(NLINK_MSG_LEN));

  //fill the iovec structure
  struct iovec iov;
  memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));
  //define the message header for message
  //sending
  struct msghdr msg;
  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));

  int sender_pid;
  printf("Receiver process id: %d\n", getpid());
  printf("Sender process id: ");
  scanf("%d", &sender_pid);

  src_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;   //AF_NETLINK socket protocol
  src_addr.nl_pid = getpid();               //application unique id
  src_addr.nl_groups = 0;            //specify not a multicast communication

  dest_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK; // protocol family
  dest_addr.nl_pid = sender_pid;   //destination process id
  dest_addr.nl_groups = 0; 

  nlh->nlmsg_len = NLMSG_SPACE(NLINK_MSG_LEN);   //netlink message length 
  nlh->nlmsg_pid = getpid();                            //src application unique id
  nlh->nlmsg_flags = 0;

  iov.iov_base = (void *)nlh;     //netlink message header base address
  iov.iov_len = nlh->nlmsg_len;   //netlink message length
  msg.msg_name = (void *)&dest_addr;
  msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(dest_addr);
  msg.msg_iov = &iov;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

  //attach socket to unique id or address
  if(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr, sizeof(src_addr)) < 0) {
    printf("Bind failed");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Listen forever in a while loop */
  while (1) {
    //receive the message
    recvmsg(fd, &msg, 0);
    printf("Received message: %s\n", (char *)NLMSG_DATA(nlh));
  }
  close(fd); // close the socket
}
```

Sender's code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NLINK_MSG_LEN 1024
#define NETLINK_USER 31

int main() {
  int fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_GENERIC);
  //int fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_USERSOCK);
  //int fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_USER);
  printf("Inside send main\n");

  if (fd < 0) {
    printf("Socket creation failed. try again\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Declare for src NL sockaddr, dest NL sockaddr, nlmsghdr, iov, msghr */
  struct sockaddr_nl src_addr, dest_addr;
  memset(&src_addr, 0, sizeof(src_addr));
  memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));

  //allocate buffer for netlink message which is message header + message payload
  struct nlmsghdr *nlh =(struct nlmsghdr *) malloc(NLMSG_SPACE(NLINK_MSG_LEN));
  memset(nlh, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(NLINK_MSG_LEN));

  //fill the iovec structure
  struct iovec iov;
  memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));
  //define the message header for message
  //sending
  struct msghdr msg;
  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));

  int receiver_pid;
  printf("Sender process id: %d\n", getpid());
  printf("Receiver process id: ");
  scanf("%d", &receiver_pid);

  src_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;   //AF_NETLINK socket protocol
  src_addr.nl_pid = getpid();               //application unique id
  src_addr.nl_groups = 0;            //specify not a multicast communication

  dest_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK; // protocol family
  dest_addr.nl_pid = receiver_pid;   //destination process id
  dest_addr.nl_groups = 0; 

  nlh->nlmsg_len = NLMSG_SPACE(NLINK_MSG_LEN);   //netlink message length 
  nlh->nlmsg_pid = getpid();                            //src application unique id
  nlh->nlmsg_flags = 0;
  strcpy(NLMSG_DATA(nlh), "Hello World !");   //copy the payload to be sent

  iov.iov_base = (void *)nlh;     //netlink message header base address
  iov.iov_len = nlh->nlmsg_len;   //netlink message length
  msg.msg_name = (void *)&dest_addr;
  msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(dest_addr);
  msg.msg_iov = &iov;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

  //attach socket to unique id or address
  if(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr, sizeof(src_addr)) < 0) {
    printf("Bind failed");
    return -1;
  }

  //send the message
  sendmsg(fd, &msg, 0);
  printf("Send message %s\n", (char *)NLMSG_DATA(nlh));

  close(fd); // close the socket
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of protocol to `socket`. The only one which can do what you want, IPC between user-space processes, is `NETLINK_USERSOCK`.

Bear in mind that in the way you are arranging communication with PIDs, you might miss some messages... For the purposes of verifying the communication does happen, you can leave `msg_name` `NULL` *for the receiver* and that will have no ill effect(s) - doing so & changing protocol, your code works as expected.

Comment: I changed `fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_GENERIC);` to `fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_USERSOCK)` and `msg.msg_name = (void *)&dest_addr` to `msg.msg_name = NULL`, but still not works.

Comment: I changed both receiver and sender to `msg.msg_name = NULL`, it would not work. But I realized and changed back the sender only to `msg.msg_name = (void *)&dest_addr`, it worked, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I realised I was too vague on that point - fixed the text. Glad you figured it out!